# wifi sometimes not working on any OS

Tags: networking, usb, 22.04, iwlwifi, firmware

For about two weeks now my wifi sometimes does not work. I am almost always able to connect over USB to a hotspot on my phone (I say almost, because at some point none of the USB ports worked until I rebooted). I have spent numerous hours researching the problem, but to no avail.

**OS: Kubuntu 22.04, Kernel 5.15.0-52-generic (64-bit)**

An excerpt of journalctl -b (this comes up almost every time I boot):

```
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb usb3-port10: attempt power cycle
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: Device not responding to setup address.
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: Device not responding to setup address.
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: device not accepting address 8, error -71
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: Device not responding to setup address.
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: Device not responding to setup address.
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb 3-10: device not accepting address 9, error -71
Okt 21 21:21:16 sven-Swift-SF514-54T kernel: usb usb3-port10: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Output of some of the commands I found in other answers here on askubuntu:

```
sven@sven-Swift-SF514-54T:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:34f0] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:0074]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
sven@sven-Swift-SF514-54T:~$ rfkill list
sven@sven-Swift-SF514-54T:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    6.945792] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    6.945803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    6.946021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.091087] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x338
[    8.135424] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x3100000
[    8.135457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc00c0538
[    8.135486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x0
[    8.135490] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    8.135594] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    8.135597] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: -1417784595
[    8.135601] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-66.ucode
[    8.135604] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE57B5FFF | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    8.135608] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA7CD2305 | trm_hw_status0
[    8.135610] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x834BF4EC | trm_hw_status1
[    8.135612] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAC97F1FD | branchlink2
[    8.135614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBABAB3E6 | interruptlink1
[    8.135617] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x14A50F4A | interruptlink2
[    8.135619] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8BE9F6B7 | data1
[    8.135621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2E24488E | data2
[    8.135623] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x96F7B63F | data3
[    8.135625] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7707DC2F | beacon time
[    8.135627] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x98E0D026 | tsf low
[    8.135629] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBEF3346D | tsf hi
[    8.135632] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDBF89C6C | time gp1
[    8.135634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3C0D6D1A | time gp2
[    8.135636] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8448054A | uCode revision type
[    8.135638] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA71FAB7E | uCode version major
[    8.135640] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8960C216 | uCode version minor
[    8.135643] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5179495E | hw version
[    8.135645] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD5DCE1B0 | board version
[    8.135647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0102C74 | hcmd
[    8.135649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6B12F23F | isr0
[    8.135651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBB250205 | isr1
[    8.135653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5FCAD8F7 | isr2
[    8.135655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2E8F0148 | isr3
[    8.135657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x55C46863 | isr4
[    8.135659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xED094436 | last cmd Id
[    8.135662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x88C63EDC | wait_event
[    8.135664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x83D5AC13 | l2p_control
[    8.135666] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x85A7A7BF | l2p_duration
[    8.135668] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8042FC65 | l2p_mhvalid
[    8.135670] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x26406153 | l2p_addr_match
[    8.135673] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x863408B8 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    8.135675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2FF76A9E | timestamp
[    8.135677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x937E9F1E | flow_handler
[    8.135721] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    8.135723] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 1238327289
[    8.135726] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8E39218B | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    8.135729] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3F9EFFD6 | umac branchlink1
[    8.135731] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1699800F | umac branchlink2
[    8.135734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCCB9B964 | umac interruptlink1
[    8.135736] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x88A82886 | umac interruptlink2
[    8.135738] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1E4A350C | umac data1
[    8.135740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4EA78C5F | umac data2
[    8.135742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC5F37BFD | umac data3
[    8.135744] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB4069992 | umac major
[    8.135746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB57CEFFE | umac minor
[    8.135748] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x11195800 | frame pointer
[    8.135751] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBA3A7DD6 | stack pointer
[    8.135753] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x009A893C | last host cmd
[    8.135755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB7848994 | isr status reg
[    8.135779] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[    8.135781] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0310 | IML/ROM SYSASSERT
[    8.135784] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x03100000 | IML/ROM error/state
[    8.135809] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM data1
[    8.135820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80000400 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    8.135846] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    8.135867] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000041 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    8.135872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    8.135894] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    8.135898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    8.135920] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    8.135924] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    8.135946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    8.135950] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    8.135972] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.136016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.136097] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    8.136180] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    8.136201] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    8.136204] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    9.165048] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    9.177697] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
[    9.184813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x338
[   10.215446] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x3100000
[   10.215478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc00c0538
[   10.215508] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   10.215512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   10.215616] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   10.215618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 795759303
[   10.215622] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-66.ucode
[   10.215625] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE57B5FDA | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   10.215628] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x87CD1705 | trm_hw_status0
[   10.215631] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8F49F67D | trm_hw_status1
[   10.215633] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA49771FE | branchlink2
[   10.215635] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBAAAB366 | interruptlink1
[   10.215637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x14C1574A | interruptlink2
[   10.215639] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8BE9E6BF | data1
[   10.215641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2A769CCA | data2
[   10.215643] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDFA7743D | data3
[   10.215645] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x172DDCEF | beacon time
[   10.215647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x28E0D226 | tsf low
[   10.215649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBEF3B227 | tsf hi
[   10.215651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDFF8186C | time gp1
[   10.215653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3C0D6D0A | time gp2
[   10.215654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80E88100 | uCode revision type
[   10.215656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA71FA37E | uCode version major
[   10.215657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9960C217 | uCode version minor
[   10.215660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5178615E | hw version
[   10.215662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x75DCE5B0 | board version
[   10.215664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0100974 | hcmd
[   10.215666] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0A96F2FF | isr0
[   10.215669] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF3250207 | isr1
[   10.215671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDECADCB3 | isr2
[   10.215673] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA40B0148 | isr3
[   10.215675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x35C4EB63 | isr4
[   10.215677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAD0B6436 | last cmd Id
[   10.215679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x888228DC | wait_event
[   10.215681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9A91AC13 | l2p_control
[   10.215683] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x93A7A7BF | l2p_duration
[   10.215685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x10D2DC65 | l2p_mhvalid
[   10.215687] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x24406853 | l2p_addr_match
[   10.215689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x023422BC | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   10.215691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEFDD612E | timestamp
[   10.215693] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x937E1E3B | flow_handler
[   10.215737] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   10.215739] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 1238327217
[   10.215742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8E3847C3 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   10.215745] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3F96FD86 | umac branchlink1
[   10.215747] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0F99801D | umac branchlink2
[   10.215749] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x88B9BB61 | umac interruptlink1
[   10.215751] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01A82886 | umac interruptlink2
[   10.215753] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1E2A6584 | umac data1
[   10.215755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4EA7045F | umac data2
[   10.215757] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEF32735C | umac data3
[   10.215759] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB4069932 | umac major
[   10.215761] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFD7CEFD2 | umac minor
[   10.215763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x34194811 | frame pointer
[   10.215765] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB2F87D92 | stack pointer
[   10.215767] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x009A8925 | last host cmd
[   10.215769] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAEAC8995 | isr status reg
[   10.215792] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   10.215794] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0310 | IML/ROM SYSASSERT
[   10.215796] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x03100000 | IML/ROM error/state
[   10.215822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM data1
[   10.215832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80000400 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   10.215840] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   10.215861] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000041 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   10.215865] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   10.215887] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   10.215892] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   10.215913] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   10.215917] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   10.215939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   10.215943] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   10.215965] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.216001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.216085] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   10.216168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   10.216189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   10.216193] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   11.239141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   11.251615] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
[   11.256596] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x338
[   12.295400] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x3100000
[   12.295434] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc00c0538
[   12.295463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   12.295467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   12.295595] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   12.295598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 963518151
[   12.295601] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-66.ucode
[   12.295604] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD57B5FFF | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   12.295608] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x26CDB305 | trm_hw_status0
[   12.295610] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x834BF6BF | trm_hw_status1
[   12.295612] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA4B271FE | branchlink2
[   12.295614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFABAB366 | interruptlink1
[   12.295616] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x04804B4A | interruptlink2
[   12.295618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8B6186B7 | data1
[   12.295621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2E249CCA | data2
[   12.295622] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD7A7743F | data3
[   12.295624] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x772DDC7F | beacon time
[   12.295626] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x98E09136 | tsf low
[   12.295628] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1CF36627 | tsf hi
[   12.295630] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAF8DD6C | time gp1
[   12.295632] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3C0D6D1A | time gp2
[   12.295634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x84480552 | uCode revision type
[   12.295637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8D1FA37E | uCode version major
[   12.295639] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0160C247 | uCode version minor
[   12.295641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1579615E | hw version
[   12.295643] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x15CCE1B0 | board version
[   12.295645] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD0000978 | hcmd
[   12.295647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAA92F4BF | isr0
[   12.295649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFF250215 | isr1
[   12.295651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDE9A5823 | isr2
[   12.295653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2C0B0148 | isr3
[   12.295655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x55C46863 | isr4
[   12.295657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9F094D76 | last cmd Id
[   12.295659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x88E62ACC | wait_event
[   12.295661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8A95AC13 | l2p_control
[   12.295663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x81D7A7BF | l2p_duration
[   12.295665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x10D2DD65 | l2p_mhvalid
[   12.295667] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x65407145 | l2p_addr_match
[   12.295669] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x023422BB | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   12.295671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6CF56A7E | timestamp
[   12.295674] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB97EBE1A | flow_handler
[   12.295717] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   12.295719] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 1355767729
[   12.295722] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x860821D3 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   12.295725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD7BEFDD6 | umac branchlink1
[   12.295727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0699800D | umac branchlink2
[   12.295729] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0CF9F871 | umac interruptlink1
[   12.295731] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00A92886 | umac interruptlink2
[   12.295733] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5FDB6D46 | umac data1
[   12.295737] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x06A78C5F | umac data2
[   12.295739] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x07737BDF | umac data3
[   12.295740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB4069992 | umac major
[   12.295741] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB559EFF8 | umac minor
[   12.295743] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x30510890 | frame pointer
[   12.295744] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBA3A7DD6 | stack pointer
[   12.295746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2A988925 | last host cmd
[   12.295747] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xADACB994 | isr status reg
[   12.295770] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   12.295773] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0310 | IML/ROM SYSASSERT
[   12.295775] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x03100000 | IML/ROM error/state
[   12.295800] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM data1
[   12.295811] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80000400 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   12.295818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   12.295840] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000041 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   12.295844] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   12.295866] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   12.295870] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   12.295892] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   12.295896] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   12.295918] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   12.295922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   12.295944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.295979] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.296063] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   12.296147] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   12.296168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   12.296171] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   13.315518] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   13.327337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

And, finally, the output of "journalctl -f" while I executed "sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service" in another terminal:

```
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T sudo[2961]:     sven : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/sven ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T sudo[2961]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by sven(uid=1000)
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Deactivated successfully.
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager Wait Online.
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager Wait Online...
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1666380500.9641] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1666380500.9730] exiting (success)
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Deactivated successfully.
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Okt 21 21:28:20 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.0027] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (after a restart)
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.0027] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.0056] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T sudo[2961]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.0084] manager[0x556b7e00a000]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.0085] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T dbus-daemon[747]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.93' (uid=0 pid=2965 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T dbus-daemon[747]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1552] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1553] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "sven-Swift-SF514-54T"
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1557] dns-mgr[0x556b7dfe94a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1563] manager[0x556b7e00a000]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1564] manager[0x556b7e00a000]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1583] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1588] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1602] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1605] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1609] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1613] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1614] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1615] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1621] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1622] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1622] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1622] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T dbus-daemon[747]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.93' (uid=0 pid=2965 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1684] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1684] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1690] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1700] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T dbus-daemon[747]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1832] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1835] agent-manager: agent[fc16ea541168211c,:1.63/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1000]: agent registered
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T NetworkManager[2965]: <info>  [1666380501.1858] manager: startup complete
Okt 21 21:28:21 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: Finished Network Manager Wait Online.
Okt 21 21:28:31 sven-Swift-SF514-54T systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: Intermittent wifi problems are almost always due to network problems or because of physical or electromagnetic interference (location). If there was a hardware, driver, or software issue, it would either work or not work.

Comment: @Nmath That seems odd. My phone and other people's laptops clearly recognize the wifi connections in the area, only my laptop says "No connections available". Connections are not shown on Windows either (I have a dualboot).

Comment: *"Connections are not shown on Windows either"* -- that certainly proves my suggestion that your issue is not related to Ubuntu...

Comment: @Nmath I see. In that case, it is likely a hardware issue. Thank you.